# Package import works in Python Interactive window (in VSCode) but not in terminal-run python?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, terminal, module, importerror

I have a custom Python package (`my_package`) located in a directory (`super_dir`). I have a script (`my_script.py`) in a nested directory of `super_dir` (let's call it `sub_dir`) that imports `my_package` and uses it.

I receive a `ModuleNotFound` error if I run the script from a terminal window (where my working directory is `super_dir`) by calling `python sub_dir/my_script.py.` It *does* work, however, if `my_script.py` is located within `super_dir`, rather than within `sub_dir` and I simply call `python my_script.py`. It also works if I run `my_script.py` in VSCode in the Python Interactive window (even if I'm my working directory is `sub_dir`)  as long as I have the lines

```
import os
os.chdir('....further_paths/super_dir/')
```

at the top of the script.

My question is: how can I get the script to run *from the terminal* such that it can remain within `sub_dir` but will still be able to import `my_package`, even though `my_package` is located 'up' a whole directory?

Even if the lines^ above (that change the current directory) are included at the top of the script, I still get the `ModuleNotFound` error as long as I run the script from a terminal window and `my_script.py` is not located in `super_dir`.

Thank you in advance, I hope my question was clear!

Comment: So you have the layout of `super_dir/my_package.py` and `super_dir/sub_dir/my_script.py`?

Comment: Yes exactly -- except that it's really `super_dir/my_package/init.py` and `super_dir/my_package/my_functions.py` since there are modules and `.py` files within the overarching `my_package`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two options. One is you need to set `PYTHONPATH` to `super_dir` so that when Python executes your script it looks there for packages during import.

The other option is to make `my_script` a module and you use `python -m sub_dir.my_script` to execute the code.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification! Much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

As long as the script.py you would like to import is not in a parent directory one solution is to make sure (or set) the current working directory for importing script in child directorys to work: `import child-dir.script` or `from child-dir import script`.